# Vue.js gives weird object with Observer data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm receiving data with axios like this:

```
getData() {                                        
    Axios.get(                                        
        '/vue/get-data/',                           
        {                                             
            params: {                                 
                categories: this.category,            
                activeFilters: this.activeFilters,    
            }                                         
        }                                             
    ).then((response) => {                            
        this.banners = response.data;                 
        this.setBanner();                             
    })                                                
},
```

Then I get this:

[image]

When I try `console.log(response.data.length)` I get `undefined`. What could
be going on here very weird!

When I look in my `vue-devtools` banners has 2 objects:

[image]

So how can `response.data.length` be undefined?

Comment: `response.data` isn't a string (likely its a JS object read in from JSON). So have no `length` property. To see the RAW content try `JSON.stringify(response.data)`.

Comment: @Richard I can't read any properties from the object aswell they are all undefined any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: what do you get if you do console.log(response.data)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting object not array that why `.length` is not working, and you are getting as `undefined`

```
this.banners = response.data[0];// for first
```

Or loop over this, to get each object's data

```
for(var i in response.data){
     console.log(response.data[i]);
}
```

If `to get` each value is not your purpose , and you want to just size check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6700/8927508)

Comment: thanks but why do I see 2 object's in my vue devtools. Then I should be able to say .length right?! Because it's an array.